# Unable to git clone over ssh

Tags: ssh, git

I created a bare git repository and pushed to as root. Then I ran `su myuser` and ran the following commands:

```
$ whoami
myuser
$ mkdir t
$ cd t
$ git clone ssh://myuser@mybox.net:1234/git3

Cloning into git3...
myuser@mybox.net's password:
fatal: '/git3' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

$ git clone /home/myuser/git3
Cloning into git3...
done.
```

Why is ssh failing? I can clone it by using the local path, and `whoami` shows myuser -- I am not root. Just to make sure I have the addr right I wrote `ssh myuser@mybox.net -p 1234` by copy/pasting the info rather then typing it.

I don't understand why ssh isn't working. I know i had it working on this remote box, but I upgraded from debian lenny to squeeze and recently I made various config changes. I don't understand why I can't use git with ssh here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

erm, don't you need:

```
$ git clone ssh://myuser@mybox.net:1234/home/myuser/git3
```

??

Comment: *sigh*. That solved it. i KNOW i tried that already. I must have tried it before i thought of checking the folder permission (i accidentally made it root)

Comment: What a great UI.